# Centralize img in div element with height of div is 100%

Tags: html, css, height

I have this code:

```
<header>
<div id="logo">
  <img src="img.png" width="288px" height="80px"/>
</div>
</header>
```

And this CSS:

```
header { width: 960px; height: 100px; padding: 10px; }

#logo { float: left; height: 100%; border: 1px solid #000; }

#logo img { border: 1px solid #000;  }
```

How to centralize vertically the img element in this div? I have use the display table, and table cell, but not work.

Comment: Center it how? Horizontally? Vertically? Both?

Comment: Sorry, both, but in this case really need a verticaly.

Comment: Why are you floating the logo left?

Comment: In my html I need this, =[, but you remove this, =].

Comment: [**this**](http://jsbin.com/aCoLIPa/3) works?

Comment: Partially solves. Using padding I also knew, I wanted something that the browser calculates automatically, where I increase the height of the header, it will automatically adjust. Understand?

Answer (score 1):

```
#logo { height: 100%; border: 1px solid #000; text-align:center; }
                                       -------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---
```

also remove the `float`

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zQYe4/2/)

Comment: I need vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @user2752929 [see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zQYe4/7/)  you need to define height of parent and add padding to parent..that way you can do that

Answer (score 0):

Use this tag text-align: center ; from the CSS for the image to the CSS for its parent div, so your CSS looks like this:

```
.box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 450px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-align:center
}

.box img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I need centered in vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace Your CSS like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/29uGQ/

```
header { width: 400px; height: 100px; padding: 10px; }

#logomark { height: 100%; border: 1px solid #000;position: relative;}

#logomark img { border: 1px solid #000; position: absolute;top:0;
bottom:0;left:0;right:0; margin:auto;}
```